# How to move $HOME for current user?

Tags: linux, shell

How do I move `$HOME` for the current user, as running the below returns an error for `<username>`?

```bsh
sudo usermod -m -d /path <username>

  # Error:
  usermod: user <username> is currently used by process /lib/systemd --user ...
```

Comment: As a quick & dirty workaround, I added password-less credentials to `root` on that machine, ssh'ed from outside as `root`, and was able to run `usermod` like that.

Comment: `root` should never be password-less... add an SSH key to root's `.ssh/authorized_keys`.  If your workaround is acceptable to you as an answer, please create an answer and accept it as the solution.

Comment: That's what I meant: password-less **ssh** credentials (by copying public key already in place for `<username>` from their `.ssh/authorized_keys` to that of `root`.  No, I think this is a kludge & I am looking for something like a `--force` on `usermod` or `sudo`, or a wrapper of some sort, if that makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

If you are currently an administrator, then create another temporary administrator account. Now log off from your current account log into the new one. Open terminal emulator and run command from there. Now log out from that and log on to your current account and delete the temporary administrator account. I don't recommend enabling root account and using root recovery shell for security.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _enabling root account_? This is a headless Ubuntu server with a single local administrator (`sudo`-capable user), accessed from a workstation via password-less ssh (workstation user's public key in server administrator's `.ssh/authorized_keys`). `/etc/shadow/` has `root:*:18295:0:99999:7:::`, which I assumed meant the password for root is not established. For my workaround, I appended the relevant key to `root`'s  `.ssh/authorized_keys`, then ssh'ed from the workstation into server's `root` account. Would that count as **enabling**?